# Reasons to use opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

Consider a BJT serving as an amplifier. No suppose I need to  subtract the output obtained from two such  BJT amplifiers A1 and A2.
Then I can simply  connect the output from A1 to one of the input  terminals of another transistor amplifier A3 and connect the other terminal to the output obtained from A2. In this way I can  obtain the output from A3 as the difference of two signals.

Now similarly suppose I need A non inverting amplifier. Then I can measure the output of a CE transistor amplifier in a reverse way so as to get the output in phase with the input.
Now  consider an integrator circuit. When an ac source is connected in series with a resistor and capacitor then if the function to be integrated is taken as the current then obviously the voltage gives the integrand of the function (although multiplied by the capacitance).

In all the above situations I have sen opamps being used. When the circuit arrangement is as simple as mentioned above why do we use opamps(which have complicated internal circuit arrangements)? I don't intend to be a critic but rather I want to know the actual purpose for which opamps are used at the expense of simplicity?

Comment: Waaay too much handwaving, undefined terms, and hard to follow stream of consiousness dump.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Could not get you.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic op-amps (like what you might design during course work) actually look quite similar to the circuits you're describing. The added complexity of op-amps is due to improved or added attributes. For instance higher common mode rejection (common noise on the input is not equally amplified) and higher gain. For certain simple circuits, that may not require high performance, the BJT circuits you've described may be a better choice. I recommend checking out the course notes [available here](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~karti/ece422.html) . It's the beginning of an analog design sequence for electrical engineering seniors. The notes show the clear progression from the circuits you're describing to more advanced (and more useful) operational amplifiers.

Comment: Why is it so that the gain also depends on the average of the input signals in case of a differential amplifier?

Answer (score 1):

You can design all the mentioned circuits using discrete transistors, and in some cases you may wish to, but OpAmps have attractive properties that make things easier, here are a few of the important ones:

- Huge open loop gain
- Negative feedback combined with the above which solves many issues.
- Very high input impedance
- Very low output impedance (one of the things negative feedback helps with)
- High CMRR and PSRR

The above features mean we can very easily set up a single ended, differential, non-inverting or inverting amplifier of a wide gain range and (in most cases) not have to worry about input/output loading effects (we can set input/output impedance accurately with a single resistor), thermal drift,  non-linearity, etc.

Have a read of something like [Opamps for Everyone](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slod006b/slod006b.pdf) and you should quickly see why they are so widely used.

Answer (score 1):

To take the difference of two outputs, one would probably use a diff amp configuration:

[image]

However, the output impedance of the diff amp is quite high.  To be able to drive significant loads, you would probably add a voltage gain stage followed by a current gain push-pull stage and then enclose the whole thing with global feedback for stability and linearity.

In other words, you've just made a simple discrete op amp.  Now, it may be that there are other considerations that would preclude you using an off the shelf opamp and choose to go "homebrew" and discrete instead and that's perfectly understandable.

However, most of the time, an opamp based circuit *is* simpler and does the job.